# Getting the monitor's name with EnumDisplayDevices

Tags: c++, windows

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958683/how-do-i-get-the-actual-monitor-name-as-seen-in-the-resolution-dialog) post in which someone wants to find out the name of their monitor using EnumDisplayDevices.

This is exactly what I want, and I tried to do something similar in C++ but the second call to EnumDisplayDevices never seems to return anything, I only get information about the graphics card.

```
DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
memset(&dd, 0, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
dd.cb = sizeof(dd);
int i = 0;
while(EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, i, &dd, 0))
{
    Log(_T("Device Name: %s Device String: %s"), dd.DeviceName, dd.DeviceString);

    if(EnumDisplayDevices(dd.DeviceName, 0, &dd, 0))
    {
        Log(_T("Monitor Name: %s Monitor String: %s"), dd.DeviceName, dd.DeviceString);
    }

    i++;
}
```

The output I get is

```
Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY1 Device String: NVIDIA GeForce 9300 GE
Device Name: \\.\DISPLAYV1 Device String: NetMeeting driver
Device Name: \\.\DISPLAYV2 Device String: RDPDD Chained DD
```

The target platform is XP, and I can't any *standard* way of finding out the monitor name. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I have a post with a pointer to code that can extract this from the EDID block at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237937/looking-for-a-reliable-mapping-of-forms-screen-devicename-to-monitor-edid-info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the **first call** to EnumDisplayDevices DispDev.DeviceString contains **graphic card's name**.
After **the second call** DispDev.DeviceString contains **monitor's name**.

Also see this [link](http://thetweaker.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/reading-monitor-physical-dimensions-or-getting-the-edid-the-right-way/) for other ways to get this info

```
BOOL GetMonitorInfo(int nDeviceIndex, LPSTR lpszMonitorInfo) {
    BOOL bResult = TRUE;
    FARPROC EnumDisplayDevices;
    HINSTANCE  hInstUserLib;
    DISPLAY_DEVICE DispDev;
    char szDeviceName[32];

    hInstUserLib = LoadLibrary("User32.DLL");

    EnumDisplayDevices = (FARPROC)GetProcAddress(hInstUserLib,
                                                 "EnumDisplayDevicesA");
    if(!EnumDisplayDevices) {
        FreeLibrary(hInstUserLib);
        return FALSE;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&DispDev, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
    DispDev.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);

    // After first call to EnumDisplayDevices DispDev.DeviceString 
    //contains graphic card name
    if(EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, nDeviceIndex, &DispDev, 0)) {
        lstrcpy(szDeviceName, DispDev.DeviceName);

        // after second call DispDev.DeviceString contains monitor's name 
        EnumDisplayDevices(szDeviceName, 0, &DispDev, 0);

        lstrcpy(lpszMonitorInfo, DispDev.DeviceString);
    }
    else {
        bResult = FALSE;
    }

    FreeLibrary(hInstUserLib);

    return bResult;
}
```

Comment: Hi Flot, 

Is it only possible to get names like "Plug and Play Monitor", because that's what I'm getting now. I wanted the monitors actual name, mine for instance is DELL P190S.

Comment: Are you sure that the driver is an original Dell driver and not a common Plug&Play Windows driver? Because I am getting a real name of my monitor this way.

Comment: In device manager it also just shows up as plug and play monitor, so I guess not. I thought the monitor name would come from the monitor's EDID, is this not the case and it just gets it from the driver?

Comment: EDID does not expose a public API. You can either read from registry directly: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY\<Type>\<SWnumber>\Device Parameters` or use WMI and query the Win32_DesktopMonitor.

Comment: Also see the link that I added in the answer

Comment: Thanks Flot, reading the registry isn't an option as there may be many monitors in there which have been connected in the past, and I won't know which is the one that's currently connected. Win32_DesktopMonitor wasn't introduced until Vista. Doing this in XP is a real pain, I'll check out that other link though. Cheers.

Comment: As a note re-using `DispDev` in this case didn't seem to work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524309/enumdisplaydevices-function-not-working-for-me/9524900#comment132242091_9524900 See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237937/looking-for-a-reliable-mapping-of-forms-screen-devicename-to-monitor-edid-info possibly related

Answer (score 0):

I think [Win32_DesktopMonitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be more suited to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't supported in XP so I can't use it.