# How to get vendor / model name of monitor using Direct3D 9?

Tags: windows, directx-9

My computer has a single graphics card.  I have three monitors plugged in, and my Windows desktop spreads across the three monitors.  When I right-click on the desktop and select "screen resolution", the dialog box that appears has a combobox "Display", which knows the make and model of each monitor.  So far, so good.

I’m writing an application using Direct3D 9, where I would like to present the user with the same choice of monitors. `IDirect3D9::GetAdapterCount` returns 3, one for each monitor.  If I all `IDirect3D9::GetAdapterIdentifier` for each one, the `D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9.Description` field describes my *graphics card* (e.g. "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 770") rather than the *monitor* (e.g. "Acer B243HL").

I tried calling `IDirect3D9::GetAdapterMonitor` to get an `HMONITOR`, and then `GetMonitorInfo` on that, but the string was of the form "\.\DISPLAY3".

Is there a function I can call that will return a string describing my *monitor*, the same as in the Windows screen resolution menu?  I'm limited to DirectX version 9.

**Edited to add:**

I had previously tried using [EnumDisplayDevices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but the closest string I ever got in `DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceString` was "Generic PnP Monitor".  Windows' own screen resolution settings have the exact make and model.

I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: I think this here covers your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299619/getting-the-monitors-name-with-enumdisplaydevices