# How to obtain display devices information regardless of session?

Tags: c++, winapi

I using [EnumDisplayDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that give me obtain information about the display devices in the current session.

But i need information about the display devices regardless of session. Because i create some windows service application (System process).

Does anybody know some alternative for this code:

```
vncDesktop::GetNrMonitors()
{
    if(OSversion()==3 || OSversion()==5) return 1;
    int i;
    int j=0;

    helper::DynamicFn<pEnumDisplayDevices> pd("USER32","EnumDisplayDevicesA"); // it's EnumDisplayDevices function

    if (pd.isValid())
    {
        DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
        ZeroMemory(&dd, sizeof(dd));
        dd.cb = sizeof(dd);
        for (i=0; (*pd)(NULL, i, &dd, 0); i++)
            {
                if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP)
                    if (!(dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER))j++;
            }
    }
    return j;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm slightly suspicious. Why should a service care? It isn't doing any UI, is it?

Comment: I using this service for vnc server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9526805/85371

Comment: Setting the flag to allow desktop interaction should resolve this.

Comment: The last time that flag worked was 10 years ago, in Windows XP. Windows Services don't display a user interface and aren't allowed to interact with the user in any way. They can't even assume that a user will be logged on—services run all the time in the background, even from the login screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this issue. Only need create process user - System and SessionID  - some user. And then all working fine.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>sources below</sup>

Well, the reason why this doesn't work is because session 0 isn't connected to a console. What's more, because many more video settings are per user on Windows 7 it would be bad to assume that anything you get from one user even applies to another user.

- You could also try to find the display monitors in the registry.

  The display monitors should be stored here:

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY

  The class GUID for display monitors is `{4D36E96E-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`. you can try to find the monitors in system using the Setup API (`SetupDiGetClassDevs`, ...)
- If you are coding specifically for Win7 and later, you might want to have a look at QueryDisplayConfig and related functions.

---

Sources

- [EnumDisplayDevices function not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524309/enumdisplaydevices-function-not-working-for-me/9526805#9526805)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/4384f8d2-c429-410b-87e4-1e031ddc8167